# How can I create a Collection NFT before Minting?

Tags: candy-machine

I understand that Collections are now being enforced on Candy Machines on Devnet.

This means, I have to run the the set_collection command after I created the Candy machine with the Upload command.

To do that, I need to create mi Collection NFT in advance.

How can I create a Collection NFT without using the Web tool https://collections.metaplex.com/? I understand that Web tool is to set a Collection in a "legacy" already minted collections.

I am sure there is something I am missing.
Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a programming question; likely better suited for bitcoin.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Upload command creates a default collection (its a nft that is minted to ur wallet and has no metadata). You just have to grab that nft and update its metadata using [this tool](https://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io) for example. Doing this you will have all of ur nfts directly attached to a certified collection without any issue and the update of the collection nft Metadata is really easy using the tool or using [metaboss](https://metaboss.rs/update.html) (if you already have the metadata uploaded to an storage)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I saw the Collection Token without Metadata on my Authority wallet. Which metadata should I put inside that Collection NFT?

Comment: Name, uri pointing to the json metadata like any other NFT (with the image uri inside the json). I recommend you to use https://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io/update-nft if you are on mainnet-beta. You just connect using the authority wallet and provide the Collection Token without metadata ID and will allow you to add the correspoding metadata

Comment: You are a life saviour. Will test this and come back to you. I am 6 days away from minting.