# NFT Not Showing up properly in Phantom Wallet

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine, phantom-wallet

I have a couple of questions regarding NFT's showing up in the Phantom wallet.

1. I created a new token yesterday on this page: https://app.strataprotocol.com/launchpad/manual/new. The NFT works correctly in terms of WL minting and looks to show correctly on the Solana Explorer page with image, description, and name. But inside of my Phantom wallet I don't get the image, I just get the name and description. I am trying to send these out as WL tokens and it would be helpful to have the image there as well. Any ideas why the image wouldn't be showing up in the Phantom wallet but the name and description are?
2. I minted an NFT and when I go to my Phantom wallet and look under "Your Collectables" it shows the image there but it says "Collection NFT". If I click into the NFT then it shows everything correctly (name, image, description, properties, etc). But I'm wondering why it says "Collection NFT" there when the metadata for each NFT has the following:

"collection": {
"name": "My Collection Name",
"family": "My Collection Name"
},

I did `verify_upload` and everything and it said 'ready to deploy'. I saw this post: [How to specify Metaplex NFT collection image in Phantom wallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72071604/how-to-specify-metaplex-nft-collection-image-in-phantom-wallet). But the collection data was already there when I ran the `upload` command for candy machine v2. What am I missing?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

1.- The whitelist token should appear correctly if you erase the cache of your browser.

2.- Thats the default collection NFT that is created when you ran upload, this collection NFT will be the portrait of ur NFTs while they are minted I recommend you to read this 2 answer to know what are this Collection NFT and how to change it: [How can I create a Collection NFT before Minting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72456388/how-can-i-create-a-collection-nft-before-minting/72464411#72464411), [How do I change the name of a solana collection prior to minting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72499758/how-do-i-change-the-name-of-a-solana-collection-prior-to-minting/72500455#72500455)

3.- offchain collection that is in ur metadata is deprecated and collection rn is an onchain field on every NFT

Comment: Hmmm...I tried erasing the cache and still can't see the image. No image in the Phantom Chrome Extension or in the mobile app.

Comment: Then its more related to phantom fetching the token, once took over a week to me to show the correct token. Can you check on other wallets?

Comment: OK damn. Yea I'm sending out WL Tokens and people are wondering about no image showing up. When I did it through Github token registery the image was there, at the latest, 12 hours later.

Comment: For #2 and #3..I ran the `show` command for Candy Machine. So if I take the `Collection Mint` address and past it into this url: `https://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io/update-nft`, and then add all of the required metadata..it should show with the correct Collection name and not say "Collection NFT" after any NFT is minted? Is there just one place specifically I can change the collection name? I just don't want to mess or break the image or name of the actual NFT not displaying after mint, because that is showing as it should

Comment: Exactly if you connect into the webpage using the same wallet that you used to create the Candy Machine, paste the collection nft if on the webpage and place the correct metadata, then after update that NFT all the minted and unminted nfts will appear under the correct Collection with the metadata that you provided on the webpage